# JRJC Client - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 20,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-xx [ACTIVE]

Tags: java, spring-boot, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

```
 private JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient() {
    return new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
            .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(URI.create(this.jiraUrl), this.username, this.password);
}
```

The above code is being used to get the Client Object. Now I create an issue using the below method

```
public CloseblePromiseWrapper<BasicIssue> createIssueAsync(IssueInputBuilder inpBuilder) {
    JiraRestClient cl = getJiraRestClient();

    IssueRestClient issueClient = cl.getIssueClient();

    return new CloseblePromiseWrapper<BasicIssue>(issueClient.createIssue(inpBuilder.build()),cl);
}



public class CloseblePromiseWrapper<T> {

    private Promise<T> promise;

    private JiraRestClient connectionClient;

}
```

Everything was working fine, I was able to create multiple issues asynchronously, but suddenly since yesterday I started getting this

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 20,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-xx [ACTIVE]
```

Any idea what can be the problem and how do i resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Jira server was under load?

Comment: Well its a Dev JIra, not the prod one. So shouldn't be overload. I am able to access through browser.